# Batch script is giving different output when executed in Operating System and in Winpe Environment

Tags: batch-file

I am running the below batch script to find the Windows drive and my D:\ drive.
When I am running this batch script from within the O.S the output is C drive which is correct but when I am running the same script from WinPe environment it is returning D drive but D drive is having no folder named PerfLogs.

```
@Echo ======================================formating bootable drive===================
@echo Off

for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (if exist %%a:\PerfLogs\ (set bootdrive=%%a))
for %%b in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (if exist %%b:\Image_deployment\ (set Imagedrive=%%b))

rem FORMAT %bootdrive%: /Q/Y   -------> it is commented for debugging purpose
echo %bootdrive%
echo format
pause
@Echo ======================================formating Completed========================
```

Comment: How is this related to `bash`?  If it isn't then please remove the `bash` tag.

Comment: Clear variables `bootdrive` and `imagedrive` in advance; anyway, ever tried `echo %SystemRoot%` to find the Windows drive and directory?

Comment: If you're running it from WinPE, then at least one of those drive letters will probably be used for the environment itself, and I would expect that `%~d0` would reference it without issue. I would also suggest that you find something more specific to determine the Windows drive than a root based directory name. From memory, the Windows Recovery Console checks for `\System32\drivers` and `\System32\config`, and reads the `\System32\config\SOFTWARE` hive for verification.